# Changing the link location in top links

Tags: magento-1.9, toplinks

I want to change my checkout link in the top links on my magento site to go to the basket instead of the checkout process.

I have found ways of just removing the links via XML files but no document son editing where the link takes you.

So the clarify i need to change the top link "checkout" to take the customer to the basket and not the checkout process. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link target is set in the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links::addCheckoutLink()` method.

```
$parentBlock->addLink(
    $text, 'checkout', $text,
    true, array('_secure' => true), 60, null,
    'class="top-link-checkout"'
);
```

The code above add the link to "checkout". You can rewrite this class and method to change the behavior...

*...or...*

you can change in your `checkout.xml` layout the call

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
        <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

became

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
        <action method="addCartLink"></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: I tried the XML file solution but it didnt seme to work. Also when i completely delete <reference name="top.links"> from the XML file the link still appearso n the fornt end?

Comment: Have you tried to flush the cache after each edit ?